# Retrieve files from SharePoint Online/365

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I'm new to SharePoint and I do realize that there are several posts about this subject and I have also read through them but I'm still not sure how to go about this.

I have attempted to achieve this using CSOM .NET (actually I preferred to use the REST API, but tho whole Azure registration thing proved to be a study of it's own, so I went with managed code instead).

Anyway, there is a SP site that I know the path to "https://(server)/sites/Pictures/". This place (site, list, folder or whatever it's called) contains some images that I would like to be able to list and potentially download.

Doing the following gives me the Name: "Pictures", the Count: 393 and the ServerRelativeUrl: "/sites/Pictures/Pictures".

```
    using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(site_url))
    {
        ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(usr, secure_pwd);

        Web web = ctx.Web;

        List lst_pictures = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pictures");

        ctx.Load(lst_pictures.RootFolder);

        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + lst_pictures.RootFolder.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("ItemCount: " + lst_pictures.RootFolder.ItemCount);
        Console.WriteLine("ServerRelativeUrl: " + lst_pictures.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);
    }
```

From here on I have tried several things to list and loop through the files, but whatever I try, I keep getting the same exception saying that the collection hasn't been initialized and I can't seem to get it right.

Then I have tried to see if I could somehow get help using both U2U CAM Query Builder and CAML Designer for SharePoint, but neither of these tools display the Pictures site (or list or folder) that I'm looking for.

I'm thinking that this ought to be pretty straight forward for someone who is used to the not so intuitive way of querying SP for resources via CSOM.

So, can anyone guide me as to what I do from here, so get the files listed in a way so that they can be downloaded (the link to the file should do in that regard).

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

I added the lines you suggested and I'm pretty sure that I have already had those lines in my code during previous tests, but I removed them again because it didn't work out for me - and it still doesn't :(
See the image here.

```
// lines not shown in the image
ctx.Load(lst_pictures.RootFolder);
ctx.Load(lst_pictures.RootFolder.Files);

ctx.ExecuteQuery();

Console.WriteLine("Name: " + lst_pictures.RootFolder.Name);
Console.WriteLine("ItemCount: " + lst_pictures.RootFolder.ItemCount);
Console.WriteLine("ServerRelativeUrl: " + lst_pictures.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl):

FileCollection files = lst_pictures.RootFolder.Files;
```

[image]

The first part works though, but it did that before changing the code.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

[image]

**UPDATE 3**
Updated code according to comments, still no go though.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 4: the solution**

Well it turns out that the actual problem was the nuget package installed called *Microsoft.SharePoint.Client* v.14.xxxx. It should have been the one just called *SharePoint.Client* v.15.xxxx (this one has no description but comes from Microsoft).

So, thanks to Adam for trying to help me, I will mark your answer as correct since it finally led me to the problem so it could be fixed.
Installing the correct package fixed the issue right away.
[image]

Correct package is this one.
[image]

**UPDATE 5: New subject, custom fields/columns (still using CSOM)**

1) I have the following code at the moment, but I need to get some extra properties (custom ones) from the files - what should I add to the code to do this?
2) And should I be using ListItem and not File in this case?
3) And could I even add filtering on custom fields/columns so to only retrieve a subset of the files?

```
        using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("<url>"))
        {
            ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("<usr>", "<pwd>");

            Web web = ctx.Web;

            lst = web.Lists.GetByTitle("<list name>");

            ctx.Load(lst);
            ctx.Load(lst.RootFolder);
            ctx.Load(lst.RootFolder.Folders);

            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            files = lst.RootFolder.Files;

            foreach (File f in files)
            {
                // doing stuff with some attributes like UniqueId, Name and ServerRelativeUrl, but need custom attributes as well.
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please load also the files of the rootFolder into the context, so like:

```
    ctx.Load(lst_pictures.RootFolder.Files);
```

and then You can get the collection of files in root folder of the library like:

```
    FileCollection fileCollection = lst_pictures.RootFolder.Files;
```

the complete code based on Your code is like:

```
    using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(site_url))
    {
        ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(usr, secure_pwd);

        Web web = ctx.Web;

        List lst_pictures = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pictures");

        ctx.Load(lst_pictures.RootFolder);

        // Load files of root folder to context
        ctx.Load(lst_pictures.RootFolder.Files);

        // after execute on context the rootFolder will be populated with file collection
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + lst_pictures.RootFolder.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("ItemCount: " + lst_pictures.RootFolder.ItemCount);
        Console.WriteLine("ServerRelativeUrl: " + lst_pictures.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);

        // get the file collection of the rootfolder
        FileCollection fileCollection = lst_pictures.RootFolder.Files;
        foreach (File file in fileCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"file : {file.Name} ");
        }
    }
```

the output of the code above for my example library was like this:
[image]

**Please be aware**

that if You plan to use folders in this library and put some files in does folders this approach is not enough :). You will need to first load  lst_pictures.RootFolder.Folders to context, then execute, after that foreach the collection of folders and for each folder You will need to load the files collection of this folder to get the files.
so to sum up You will need to:

```
    ctx.Load(lst_pictures.RootFolder);
    ctx.Load(lst_pictures.RootFolder.Folders);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

and then

```
    FolderCollection folderCollection = lst_pictures.RootFolder.Folders;
    foreach (Folder folder in folderCollection)
    {
           ctx.Load(folder.Files);
           ctx.ExecuteQuery();
           FileCollection fileCollection = folder.Files;
           foreach (File file in fileCollection)
           {
                 Console.WriteLine($"file : {file.Name} ");
           }
    }
```

but if You plan only to keep files in the root folder of the library the first code should be what You are looking for.
I hope this post is of any help :)

P.S.
Welcome to SharePoint.

**UPDATE 1**

If You would like to include custom columns in the files collection You need to include them. You can either include all custom columns of files like this

```
    ctx.Load(list.RootFolder);
    ctx.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
    ctx.Load(list.RootFolder.Files, includes => includes.Include(i => i.Name, i => i.ListItemAllFields));
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

and then You have the list of all columns also the custom ones. So You can do a foreach like:

```
    FileCollection fileCollection = list.RootFolder.Files;
    foreach (File file in fileCollection)
    {
          Console.WriteLine($"file : {file.Name} ");
          Console.WriteLine($"file : {file.ListItemAllFields["SomeCustomColumn"]} ");
     }
```

to get only the needed custom columns You can include them one by one like

```
    ctx.Load(list.RootFolder.Files, includes => includes.Include(i => i.Name, i => i.ListItemAllFields["CustomColumn1"], i => i.ListItemAllFields["CustomColumn2"]));
```

and then for this file collection You should have only the Name, and the two custom columns in the collection.

Please be also aware that the names of this columns are the internal field names (or static names) not the display name, so SharePoint for example can change the space to *x0020*. So For column display name like "Custom Column 1" the internal name is "Custom_x0020_Column_x0020_1" and this is the name You should use. You can get this name by going to the column settings page (edit page) and You will see the name in the url in the parameter Field=....

Comment: I tried to update the code like you suggested Adam, but it still doesn't work - I have updated my initial post.

Comment: this is strange :)... also since as You can see in my example case based on Your description it works. You could do two thinks which I hope will do the trick:
1) try to add also List in the load: so like -> ctx.Load(lst_pictures);
2) try to get the collection to var and load the var. So like ->
var files = lst_pictures.RootFolder.Files;
ctx.Load(files);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
// after this line check if files is populated with collection

Comment: jus to clarify in the site "sites/Picutres" You can see in the site content the "Pictures" list which have those images right? so this is an actual library on the site?

Comment: If i go to the site url, there is a tile called Pictures that I can click and then I see the pictures. The url (in the browser) chanegs though to /Pictures/Pictures (which the relative url in the console app also indicates).

Comment: I have updated my post again (update 2) to match your suggestions.

Comment: Ok sa you did the first suggestion to add the list to load. But did you try the second suggestion? With loading filecollection in separate variable?

Comment: No it does not :-). Please try to check and do: var files = lst_pictures.RootFolder.Files; ctx.Load(files); ctx.ExecuteQuery();... And then check if the variable files is populated?

Comment: Those exact 2 lines are the last ones in the image (UPDATE 2) just before the foreach loop...

Comment: Aaaa ok, I see it now I the picture. But still You are missing the ctx.executeQuery(). After every ctx.Load() You should executeQuery.

Comment: Ah! I see now the execute is missing... hang on.

Comment: Ye ye.. I noticed it now.. sorry for that :-). Please try to add executeQuery after load

Comment: I did that now (UPDATE 3), no change I'm afraid :(

Comment: Hmm to tell You the truth from code point of view it all seems fine... I am now thinking what kind of library those pictures is? Or maybe what nugget You are using. Ok I will check all this when I will be back in front of the computer and give You maybe more tips to check :-)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try and help me out - I have updated with an image of the Nuget packages installed on the project.

Comment: Hmm there is also a package just named SharePoint.Client with no Microsoft prefix. It appears to be of a higher version, though that wasn't the one I saw used in samples I have checked out.

Comment: Ok you know what? - I installed that other package and now it works.... How annoying is that on a scale... Only the older package has any description text and it shows up before the later version (the one without Microsoft prefix). So I appears that the code doesn't any any errors, in fact maybe it never did. Thanks a lot for taking the time Adam, appreciated :)

Comment: You tagged the question for SharePoint-online and you have a nugget for SharePoint 2010 on-prem. This may produce a lot of errors also in future. Please install the nugget: 'Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM'. no problem for the help. I know SharePoint one the begging may be hard :-)

Comment: I added the package you suggested now and it still works though this one is most likely the better choice since it appears to be newer and also has the updated Office 365 icon.

Comment: Looking at the code in the original post (UPDATE 3), what would be the easiest way to get hold on custom field/column values too please?

Comment: When loading the collection to context you need to add additional include parameter. It should look something like ctx.load(folder.Files, 'Include(Field1,Field2)'); . I don't have the possibility to check it today but as I remembered it should look something like this.

Comment: I have updated the original post (it's getting quite long) with UPDATE 5 about the custom fields. I tried to add the code you suggested but the VS intellisense didn't like much of what I tried to do, so I still didn't get it right.

Comment: sorry.. my mistake.. I added the syntax for JS.. so You could use this in JSOM not CSOM... I updated my post. please check

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot Adam for that thorough explanation, just what a SP novice like me needs :) I will check it out and see if I can get it to work, hopes are up!

Comment: I can't seem to get into the right edit page for columns so that I can see their system name. If I click a column and select Column Settings -> Edit, a pane opens to the right, but nothing happens to the URL and the system name isn't displayed anywhere that I can see. Maybe I should just go with the _x0020_ rule and assume.

Comment: Go to list settings and click on the column name in The columns section. Then you should be on a dedicated webpage for this column and the param will be one the URL